# Perceptron with unigram features, how does it learn and what are the next steps?

Tags: haskell, nlp, neural-network, perceptron

I'm learning about basic NLP algorithms, specifically simple perceptrons with unigram features.

I've looked over the basic's of perceptrons from [this](http://www.phontron.com/slides/nlp-programming-en-05-perceptron.pdf) and [this](http://pageperso.lif.univ-mrs.fr/~alexis.nasr/Ens/M2/collins-perceptron.pdf).

This is my simple Haskell perceptron, adapted from [this](http://jpmoresmau.blogspot.co.uk/2007/05/perceptron-in-haskell.html) source:

```
type Inputs = [Float] 
type Weights = [Float]
type Threshold = Float
type LearnRate = Float
type Expected = Float
type Actual = Float

neuronOutput :: (Num a, Ord a) => Inputs -> Weights -> Threshold -> a 
--neuronOutput :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> a -> a --Parametic polymorphic 
neuronOutput inputs weights thresh
| total - thresh >= 0                       = 1
| otherwise                                 = 0
where
    total = foldl (+) 0 $ zipWith (*) inputs weights


adjustWeights :: Inputs -> Weights -> Expected -> Actual -> LearnRate -> Weights --Adjust the weights 
--adjustWeights :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> a -> a -> a -> [a] --Parametic polymorphic 
adjustWeights inputs orgiWeights expected actual learn = map delta $ zip inputs orgiWeights
where 
    delta (i, w) = w + (learn * i * e)
    e = expected - actual


singleIteration :: Inputs -> Weights -> Expected -> LearnRate -> Threshold -> Weights   --Return adjusted weights based on neuronOutput
--singleIteration :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> a -> a -> a -> [a] --Parametic polymorphic 
singleIteration inputs weights expectd learn thresh = adjustWeights inputs weights expectd output learn
  where 
     output = neuronOutput inputs weights thresh



implementIterations :: [(Inputs, Expected)] -> Weights -> LearnRate -> Threshold -> (Inputs, Expected) --Applies singleIteration to each input set
implementIterations allInputs weights learnR thresH = (newWeights, delta)
 where
    newWeights = foldl iterate weights allInputs
    iterate w (i, e) = singleIteration i w e learnR thresH
    delta = (foldl (+) 0 $ map abs $ zipWith (-) newWeights weights) / (fromIntegral $ length weights) --Func composition here to make better?


runLearning :: [(Inputs, Expected)] -> LearnRate -> Threshold -> Weights -> Int -> (Inputs, Int)
runLearning allInputs learnR thresH weights epochNb
  | delta == 0              = (newWeights, epochNb)
  | otherwise               = runLearning allInputs learnR thresH newWeights (epochNb + 1) --Recusive changing weights each time
  where
    (newWeights, delta) = implementIterations allInputs weights learnR thresH


main = do
  let inputs = [([1, 1, 1], 1), ([0, 0, 0], -1)]
  let weights = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -4]
  print  $ runLearning inputs 0.1 0.2 weights 1
```

My questions are:

1) What part of this code 'learns'? I understand each feature has an associated weight (positive or negative), however I don't see how each iteration learns from the priors result?

2) What's the 'next stage' of NLP algorithms? I.e. I understand single layer perceptrons are very simple, what other neural nets structures and/or different algorithms should I be looking at for more accurate classifiers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) What part of this code 'learns'?

Learning is achieved by adjusting the weights to make the perceptron's output on the training data become closer to the desired output.

> 2) What's the 'next stage' of NLP algorithms?

I don't know anything about NLP algorithms, but perceptrons are the building blocks of neural networks. I think the next thing you'll want to look at is feed-forward back propagation neural networks. They consist of layers of connected perceptrons. Brush up on your linear algebra and multi-variable  calculus because adjusting the weights is a bit more involved!